# How to remove single quotes from string in Jolt Spec

Tags: json, apache-nifi, jolt

I am phrasing the value of a long string where the data comes with single quotes ('). how we can remove the single quotes in Jolt Specification. Please suggest.

**Input** :

```json
{
  "text": "2023-05-24 12:11:06.185 google.com i-axcel: phone 'New Launch of software city' on USKANSAS changed from USNYC"
}
```

**Jolt Spec** :

```json
[
  {
    "operation": "shift",
    "spec": {
      "text": ["description_cpy2"]
    }
  },
  {
    "operation": "modify-overwrite-beta",
    "spec": {
      "description_cpy2": "=split('phone',@(1,description_cpy2))",
      "pharse": "=split('changed',@(1,description_cpy2[1]))",
      "pharseone": "@(1,pharse[0])",
      "pharsetwo": "@(1,pharse[0])"
    }
  },
  {
    "operation": "modify-overwrite-beta",
    "spec": {
      "pharseone": "=trim",
      "pharsetwo": "=trim"
    }
  },
  {
    "operation": "shift",
    "spec": {
      "pharseone": "pharseone",
      "pharsetwo": "pharsetwo"
    }
  }
]
```

**Current Output** :

```json
{
  "pharseone" : "'New Launch of software city' on USKANSAS",
  "pharsetwo" : "'New Launch of software city' on USKANSAS"
}
```

**Expected output :**

```json
{
  "pharseone" : "New Launch of software city on USKANSAS",
  "pharsetwo" : "New Launch of software city on USKANSAS"
}
```

Answer (score 3):

It doesn't have a straight way with functions in Jolt, But you can use the `shift` operation to get `'` separately and remove them.

```json
[
  {
    "operation": "shift",
    "spec": {
      "text": ["description_cpy2"]
    }
  },
  {
    "operation": "modify-overwrite-beta",
    "spec": {
      "description_cpy2": "=split('phone',@(1,description_cpy2))",
      "pharse": "=split('changed',@(1,description_cpy2[1]))",
      "pharseone": "@(1,pharse[0])",
      "pharsetwo": "@(1,pharse[0])"
    }
  },
  {
    "operation": "modify-overwrite-beta",
    "spec": {
      "pharseone": "=trim",
      "pharsetwo": "=trim",
      "pharseon*": "=split('',@(1,pharseone))",
      "pharsetw*": "=split('',@(1,pharsetwo))"
    }
  },
  {
    "operation": "shift",
    "spec": {
      "pharse*": {
        "*": {
          "'": {
            "@1": "temp_&3"
          },
          "*": {
            "@1": "&3"
          }
        }
      }
    }
  },
  {
    "operation": "remove",
    "spec": {
      "temp_*": ""
    }
  },
  {
    "operation": "modify-overwrite-beta",
    "spec": {
      "*": "=join('',@(1,&))"
    }
  }
]
```